# PL/SQL - Create tables based on cursor using execute immediate?

Tags: sql, loops, plsql, cursor, execute-immediate

I've written the following code that selects some student test data and using a cursor, inserts it into a table.
What id like to be able to do is create one table for **each** student and insert their relative data. This could be one row or multiple rows.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_student_scores 

  IS

  CURSOR c_pass_fail_cursor
    IS
  SELECT students.firstname,
      test_history.score,
      test_id.test_name,
      test_id.passing_grade
  FROM students
  INNER JOIN test_history
    ON students.student_id = test_history.student_id
  INNER JOIN test_id
    ON test_id.test_id = test_history.test_id
    WHERE test_history.start_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(sysdate) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR 
      AND to_timestamp(sysdate) + INTERVAL '21' HOUR;

v_name    students.firstname%TYPE;
v_score   test_history.score%TYPE;
v_test    varchar2(40);
v_passing test_id.passing_grade%TYPE;
v_result  varchar2(4);

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('create table student_tests_' || (to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')) ||     '(student_name VARCHAR2(20), test_name varchar2(40), test_score NUMBER(3), pass_rate     NUMBER(3), pass_fail VARCHAR2(4))');

OPEN c_pass_fail_cursor;
 LOOP
FETCH c_pass_fail_cursor INTO v_name, v_score, v_test, v_passing;
EXIT WHEN c_pass_fail_cursor%NOTFOUND;
If v_score < v_passing 
  THEN v_result := 'Fail';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ' ' || v_score || ' ' || v_test || ' ' || V_passing || ' ' || 'Result =' || v_result);
ELSE
  v_result := 'Pass';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ' ' || v_score || ' ' || v_test || ' ' || V_passing || ' ' || 'Result =' || v_result);
END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO student_tests_' || (to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')) || ' ' || ' values(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)' using v_name, v_test, v_score, v_passing, v_result;

END LOOP;

CLOSE c_pass_fail_cursor; 

END;
/
```

I've played around with it for the last couple of days and cant get it to work. The closest i can get is to create the tables and insert the first row only, generating an error when the loop tries to create a table that already exists.

Any help would be awesome

Thanks folks

Ben

Comment: Why would you want to create an individual table for each student?

Comment: Hi silentsurfer. I'd rather not have to, but its one of some practice questions in a PLSQL training course. I could just skip it, but id really like to know how to do it.

Comment: @bkm, the issue looks to me to be one of non-unique table names. I think rather than appending `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')` to the table name, it should be a unique value for the student. If `student_name` is unique then I would suggest using that, otherwise perhaps create a sequence (`SYS_GUID()` would be too long for a table name in Oracle).

Comment: Hi David. I've tried moving the execute immediate create and insert into the loop and adding a variable based on the student to the table name. However, because of the loop, if the student has more than one row of test data, i get an existing object error as you suggested. Could you give me an example on the 'create a sequence' suggestion?

Comment: @bkm, do you really want a new table for each grade the student receives? I would think one table per student, max. But if you really want to use a sequence to create a unique table name, create the sequence and then use `mysequence.nextval` to create a unique table name.

Comment: Hi David, you're right, i do only want one table per student. The problem im having is with students with more than one line of data. If i use a loop i get a table already exists error and i cant work out an alternative way to create the tables. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Outcome: 1 table for each student (unique by name).

The `create table ...` is now inside the loop surrounded by an exception block. If the table already exists, the exception (ORA-00955) is handled.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_student_scores 

IS

  CURSOR c_pass_fail_cursor
    IS
  SELECT students.firstname,
      test_history.score,
      test_id.test_name,
      test_id.passing_grade
  FROM students
  INNER JOIN test_history
    ON students.student_id = test_history.student_id
  INNER JOIN test_id
    ON test_id.test_id = test_history.test_id
    WHERE test_history.start_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(sysdate) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR 
      AND to_timestamp(sysdate) + INTERVAL '21' HOUR;

v_name    students.firstname%TYPE;
v_score   test_history.score%TYPE;
v_test    varchar2(40);
v_passing test_id.passing_grade%TYPE;
v_result  varchar2(4);

    --New variables
    table_already_exists EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_already_exists, -955);
BEGIN

OPEN c_pass_fail_cursor;
 LOOP
FETCH c_pass_fail_cursor INTO v_name, v_score, v_test, v_passing;
EXIT WHEN c_pass_fail_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    begin
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('create table student_tests_' || v_name  || ' (student_name VARCHAR2(20), test_name varchar2(40), test_score NUMBER(3), pass_rate     NUMBER(3), pass_fail VARCHAR2(4))');
    exception when table_already_exists then
        null;
    end;

If v_score < v_passing 
  THEN v_result := 'Fail';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ' ' || v_score || ' ' || v_test || ' ' || V_passing || ' ' || 'Result =' || v_result);
ELSE
  v_result := 'Pass';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ' ' || v_score || ' ' || v_test || ' ' || V_passing || ' ' || 'Result =' || v_result);
END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO student_tests_' || v_name || ' ' || ' values(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)' using v_name, v_test, v_score, v_passing, v_result;

END LOOP;

CLOSE c_pass_fail_cursor; 

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Grafros answer looks good, but i strongly recommend to take a look at [DBMS_ASSERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#CHDIFDJE) with DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME or DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL whenever you have take abitrary strings and use them in execute immidiate.